# Can't launch Mac OS 9

Tags: classic-mac-os

Need to launch Mac OS 9 but it says it is no longer supported, is there a way around that? I am trying to put it and an old version of QuarkXpress on an old 40 GB external hard drive.  I need access to both to open up some old important files.

What are my options?

Comment: What model of Mac are you using? 10.4 was the last version of OS X that was capable of booting into Classic.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1: Run OS9 Emulator and install QuarkXpress:**
Found here for free: [emaculation.com](http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=7360&sid=849aea31ab4978b39cf96a67d0065463)

**Option 2: Change filename to work on current QuarkXpress:**
Assuming you have QuarkXpress on your new mac all you have to do is add the `.qxp` filename extension at the end of your old filenames and it will open on new versions.